# How to read JSON array in PHP and store it in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm newbie with PHP and JSON. I have a script that collects data from an JSON API and stores it in to MySQL data-base.

Script is working fine but I have a problem collecting specific array data.
This is the script :

```
<?php
$url="";
$db_name=" ";
$db_server=" ";
$db_user=" ";
$db_password="";
$newline=PHP_EOL;

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_server,$db_user, $db_password,  $db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}else{
echo "You are connected to the database ($db_name)" . $newline;
}
echo "Initial character set: ". $mysqli->character_set_name(). $newline;
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
echo "Error loading character set utf8: ", $mysqli->error. $newline;
exit();
} else {
echo "Current character set: ", $mysqli->character_set_name(). $newline;
}

$json = file_get_contents($url . '1}');
$obj = json_decode(utf8_encode($json));
$totalPages=$obj->totalPages;


//read page
for($i = 1; $i < $totalPages ; $i++) {
echo "Read URL " . $url . $i . '}'. $newline;
$json = file_get_contents($url . $i . '}');
$obj = json_decode($json);

foreach($obj->items as $item){
    $id = $item->id;
    $Name=$item->name;
    $FirstName = $item->firstName;
    $LastName = $item->lastName;

    $attributes = $item->attributes;
    foreach($attributes as $attribute){
         if ($attribute->name=="fut.attribute.DIV"){
            $DIV = $attribute->value;
         } 
         if ($attribute->name=="fut.attribute.POS"){
            $POS = $attribute->value;
         }
    }

    $r = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM DATABAS WHERE id=". $id);
    if ($r->num_rows <= 0){ //INSERT

        $query = "INSERT INTO DATABASE ( ";
        $query.= "`id`  , ";
        $query.= "`Name` , ";
        $query.= "`FirstName` , ";
        $query.= "`LastName` , ";
        $query.= "`DIV` ,";
        $query.= "`POS` ) VALUES (";

        $query.= $id . " , ";
        $query.= "'" . $Name . "' , ";
        $query.= "'" . $FirstName . "' , ";
        $query.= "'" . $LastName . "' , ";
        $query.= "'" . $DIV. "' , ";
        $query.= "'" . $POS. "'  ";
        $query.= ");";

        $mysqli->query($query);
        echo "Last Name inserted was: " . $Name . $newline;

    }else{ //UPDATE

        $query = "UPDATE database  ";
        $query.= "SET `Name` ='".$Name."' , ";
        $query.= "`FirstName` ='".$FirstName."' , ";
        $query.= "`LastName` ='".$LastName."' , ";
        $query.= "`DIV`='".$DIV."' , ";
        $query.= "`POS`='".$POS."' ";
        $query.= "WHERE id=".$id;

        $mysqli->query($query);
        echo "Last ID update was: " . $_id . $newline;

    }

}
}   
$mysqli->close();


function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}
function unicode_decode($str) {
return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9af]{4})/i',            'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);
}
```

The Json data which I like to add is Traits "traits" and Specialties `specialities`. Data is stored with `[]` and I simply have now idea how to read it.
Attributes are stored likewise but have fixed names to point to. 
This is partial Json data:

```
,"position":"RW","playStyle":"Basic","playStyleId":null,"height":170,"weight":72,"birthdate":"1987-06-24","age":29,"acceleration":99,"aggression":58,"agility":95,"balance":98,"ballcontrol":99,"foot":"Left","skillMoves":4,"crossing":90,"curve":99,"dribbling":99,"finishing":99,"freekickaccuracy":99,"gkdiving":6,"gkhandling":11,"gkkicking":15,"gkpositioning":14,"gkreflexes":8,"headingaccuracy":99,"interceptions":36,"jumping":82,"longpassing":89,"longshots":97,"marking":21,"penalties":82,"positioning":99,"potential":95,"reactions":95,"shortpassing":99,"shotpower":89,"slidingtackle":35,"sprintspeed":96,"standingtackle":38,"stamina":91,"strength":71,"vision":99,"volleys":94,"weakFoot":4,"traits":["Shooting - Finesse Shot","Dribbler - Speed Dribbler","One Club Player","Ultimate Professional"],"specialities":["Speedster","Dribbler","Distance Shooter","Crosser","FK Specialist","Acrobat","Clinical Finisher","Complete Forward","Poacher"],"atkWorkRate":"Medium","defWorkRate":"Low","playerType":"TEAM OF THE YEAR","attributes":[{"name":"fut.attribute.PAC","value":99,"chemistryBonus":[0]},{"name":"fut.attribute.SHO","value":98,"chemistryBonus":[0]},{"name":"fut.attribute.PAS","value":97,"chemistryBonus":[0]},{"name":"fut.attribute.DRI","value":99,"chemistryBonus":[0]},{"name":"fut.attribute.DEF","value":40,"chemistryBonus":[0]},{"name":"fut.attribute.PHY","value":75,"chemistryBonus":[0]}],"name":"Messi","quality":"gold","color":"toty","isGK":false,"positionFull":"Right
```

I really hoop some can help me. I try to find the solution myself but the solutions I have seen don’t correspond with the used code and my lack of knowledge on the subject is limiting me to implement it myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_decode($json_obj,true);//decode object  
foreach($arr as $ar){

        $id = $ar["id"];
        $name = $ar["name"];
        $system_id = $ar["system_id"];
        $max_landing_pad_size = $ar["max_landing_pad_size"];
        $distance_to_star = $ar["distance_to_star"];
        $faction = $ar["faction"];
        $government = $ar["government"];
        $allegiance = $ar["allegiance"];
        $state = $ar["state"];
        $type = $ar["type"];
        $has_blackmarket = $ar["has_blackmarket"];
        $has_commodities = $ar["has_commodities"];
        $has_refuel = $ar["has_refuel"];
        $has_repair = $ar["has_repair"];
        $has_rearm = $ar["has_rearm"];
        $has_outfitting = $ar["has_outfitting"];
        $has_shipyard = $ar["has_shipyard"];

        //insert values into mysql database
        $sql="INSERT INTO stations (station_id, name, system_id, max_landing_pad_size, distance_to_star, faction, government, allegiance, state, type, has_blackmarket, has_commodities, has_refuel, has_repair, has_rearm, has_outfitting, has_shipyard) 
        VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$system_id', '$max_landing_pad_size', '$distance_to_star', '$faction', '$government', '$allegiance', '$state', '$type', '$has_blackmarket', '$has_commodities', '$has_refuel', '$has_repair', '$has_rearm', '$has_outfitting', '$has_shipyard')";

        if(!mysql_query($sql,$con)) //$con is mysql connection object
        {
             die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
        }

}
```

Comment: Do I need to replace my total code and build it like in your example or do I need to insert this code in to the existing file ?(with my own values of course)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using MySQL 5.7 just have a column in the table of data type JSON and just write the JSON object or array into it.

Comment: Thanks David, Unfortunately I'm not using MySQL 5.7. Beside that means writing a whole new script which will make things more difficult for me with the fact that I barely got this one working.(with a lot of help)
Is there no way to add a code to the existing scrip like for the $attributes ?